# Is there still a ferry between Gozo and Comino?

Tags: public-transport, ferries, malta

It would be most convenient for me to travel from Gozo to Comino rather than from Malta but the two guide books I found, one updated 2019 and the other 2020, only mention one from Malta. There are some mentions of route online but I cannot find anything that confirms it is currently (Summer 2020) operating. A screenshot from Google Maps does *not* show such a path:

[image]

**Is there currently a ferry going from Gozo to Comino and back?** If so, what is its schedule?

Comment: Yes, there is one. I am back from Malta and I took one from Malta to Gozo and there is one from Cozo tot Comino.

Answer (score 10):

There is definitely a ferry service to Comino, on a recent trip I remember seeing ferries from Gozo to Comino. I found [this company](https://gozocominoferries.com/) (no affiliation) that looks like it's currently running and offers ferries from Gozo to Comino.

You can view the departure times [here](https://gozocominoferries.com/schedule/) - the 'am' on that website is a mistake, the times assume a 24 hour clock:

> ## Departure From Comino Blue Lagoon
>
> 08.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
> 09.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
> 10.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
> 11.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
> 12.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
> 13.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
> *14.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
> 15.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
> *16.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
> 17.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
> 18.15 Comino Blue Lagoon
>
> * Cave Trips On Return

Answer (score 3):

Belated, but yes: there are different options to reach Comino island either from Malta or from Gozo, and obviously for the way back. Ferries or - more easily - smaller touristic boats are chartered or scheduled by private companies, often offering both the choices of a "taxi" service (only taking passengers to Comino and back) or an additional tour around the island and its beaches and caves.

Last summer (late August 2020) I also went to Comino, from Sliema, and I do not remember which company it was. Booking in advance was not necessary and the ticket is anyway never expensive.

A quick Google search and I found [this other timetable](https://www.cominoferryservice.com/services/comino-ferry/): this company and the one cited in the previous answer are surely not the only two operating the service.